# Sqlite populado quando instala apk

Tags: delphi, sqlite, sqlite3, delphi-10

Quando compilo o app direto no celular o SQLite vem vazio (exatamente como está o arquivo no caminho especificado para o DB) mas quando uso o .apk gerado na mesma compilação ele popula o DB aparentemente com os dados da ultima instalação do mesmo apk no celular. Usando Delphi Rio 10.3. Já limpei cache e dados antes de desinstalar/instalar o app, já deletei a pasta criada pelo apk dentro da pasta Adroid/{app}/data, já verifiquei os parametros da conexão e os parametros de deployment para confirmar que o delphi está usando o arquivo certo.

Comment: Verifique no manifesto como esta a opção de backup,  dentro de application vai ter uma opção allowBackup, coloque para false se estiver true, ex: android:allowBackup="false"

Comment: Realmente era esse o problema. Resolvido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema solucionado adicionando a opção `android:allowBackup="false"` no arquivo AndroidManifest.template.xml na pasta do projeto.